# Road shapefiles of Thessaloniki, Greece for years 1991 and 2003?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, transportation, europe, download

I want to download the road network for the city of Thessaloniki, Greece for years 1991 and 2003 in shapefile format.

Do you know where can I find data for those years?

Comment: this is so specific (specific years, specific city) that probably you will have to go to some planner or geographer in Thessaloniki. Perhaps the 1991 data isn't digital.

Comment: Perhaps contact the universities geography department might have or not but they should direct you somewhere they know what to find it.